# HTML CSS label's inside div (div has display: inline-block;) adds padding/margin for some reason?

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

fiddler:

http://jsfiddle.net/9QeP4/1/

^^^ slide the result width to the left so it will show them all next to each other

code:

```
 <div>

<div style="display: inline-block;">
    <label>Account Name:</label> <br>
    <label>Email Address:</label> <br>
    <label>Password:</label>
</div>

<div style="display: inline-block;">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="txtAccountName"> <br>
        <input type="text" name="txtEmailAddress"> <br>
        <input type="password" name="txtPassword"> <br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>

<div style="display: inline-block;">
    <label>Some error message</label> <br>
    <label>Some other Error message</label> <br>
    <label>Why was the E capitalized in that last sentence</label>
</div>

</div>
```

Why does this add padding/margin to the labels? It pushes them down instead of being flush against the top for some reason

Answer (score 4):

Not Padding Margin issue,its alignment issue.. use `vertical-align: top;` your problem is solved.

```
<div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;">
    <label>Account Name:</label> <br>
    <label>Email Address:</label> <br>
    <label>Password:</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Html codes were not formatted properly

**HTML**

```
<div style="position: relative;">

    <div  style="float:left; display:inline-block;">
        <label>Account Name:</label> <br/>
        <label>Email Address:</label> <br/>
        <label>Password:</label>
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;display:inline-block;">
        <form action="/webroot/NewUserSignUpProcess" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="txtAccountName"/> <br/>
            <input type="text" name="txtEmailAddress"/> <br/>
            <input type="password" name="txtPassword"/> <br/>

                        <input id="newSignupSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div style="display: inline-block;float:left;">
        <label>Some error message</label> <br/>
        <label>Some other Error message</label> <br/>
        <label>Why was the E capitalized in that last sentence</label>
    </div>

</div>
```

I have formatted it

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9QeP4/5/)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a margin or padding, just follows the HTML rules.

Because all three div is inline-block, so it will show in a line.

The second block is higher than the other two, so it shows like this.

I think it is better to change your html code.
Make related controls in the same group. Or in the future, it may be harder to change the layout.